# Logic behind a thread

Tags: java

I have made a simulation of a race by:

```
// starts the timer + betting iterations
public void run() {

    for (int i = 25; i >= 0; i--) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            h.setTime(Integer.toString(i)); //h.setLblTime1(Integer.toString(i)); 

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Timer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    Thread t0 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 0)); 
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 1)); 
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 2)); 
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 3)); 

    t0.start();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    Thread.currentThread().run();

}
```

How can I do it in the proper way? (I need an automatic betting round iteration to start every 25 seconds)

Thanks.

Comment: Explain more on what you are trying to accomplish. `Thread.currentThread().run();` is a nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

usually, when you use threads, you could use variables on which take lock (with synchronize keyword).
Otherwise, you can use join() method:

```
public void run() {
  // code
}


int main() {
    Thread t0 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 0)); 
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 1)); 
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 2)); 
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new runHorses(h, 3)); 

    t0.start();
    t0.join();
    t1.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.start();
    t2.join();
    t3.start();
    t4.join();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, this is exactly what you need.